# Windows VSCode C "cannot open source file" from WSL GCC

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

Currently using VSCode on Windows for development, including C files. However, including unix header files (like <unistd.h>) results in VSCode thinking that there is an error. The current compiler path is "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" but there is a working GCC installed in WSL which is the main compiler I want to use.

[image: GCC location]
[image: Example error]

Using `wsl gcc` to compile files works and the files run normally. There is an option for "Compiler path" and "Include path" in the Microsoft C/C++ Extension, but WSL paths (such as "\wsl.localhost", "//wsl$/Ubuntu/", "/usr/local" etc.) are not recognised by either option. Opening another VSCode window in WSL remote mode works, but doing that just for C files specifically is very slow. Is there a way to specify a configuration for non WSL VSCode windows to use the WSL GCC compiler for C code analysis?

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to do is set the compiler path.If you do that, you won't need to manually set the system to include paths and defines.

[VS Code Website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl)

Comment: Invalid link. Update it

Comment: Sorry for the link. I updated it